# 4 Bit ALU addition

Tags: alu

What are the values of the Z, V, C and N bits in the status register after the operation 1000 + 1111 for a 4-bit ALU?

Comment: @Camil Staps I tried adding the binaries together, but currently I am re reading over what each letter represents in regards to the ALU, e.g. zero flag etc

Comment: In doing this I guess the C = 1 and the and N = 0 V  = 1 and Z = 1? I think that could be the answer but... any clarification on that?

Comment: The first step is: what would be the 5 bit result value? (5 bits because it makes you notice any carry)

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen 5 bit result would be 10111 I believe

Comment: Correct, and what happens next... what do the Z, V, C and N status bits do? What are their names and how is the answer (10111) going to affect the status bits. I think you are nearly there dude... just a little more confidence and practise.

Comment: @Andyaka Z is the zeroflag, C is the carry N is the negative and V is the overflow, I assumed C is carry out of the MSB which is 1? N is 0 since thats the sign of the 4 bit result 0111, V is overflow so wouldn't that mean it would be 1 ? the only one I'm not so sure about is Z, although it says, the indicates that the result of an arithmetic operation was zero, so I assume it would have to be 1 also? but then again I could have totally stuffed all of those up :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at bit level what happens in an addition. We're going to add `1111` to `1000`.

- First, take the Least Significant Bits (LSB, the most right). We have a 1 and a 0. Summed, that makes 1. There's no overflow here.
- Now, the second bit. Again a 1 and a 0, so again a 1. No overflow, again.
- The same goes for the third bit.
- The Most Significant Bit (MSB, the most left) is different: two ones. This gives summed a 0, with an overflow. That would mean the fifth bit would get an extra 1, however, there's no fifth bit, so the overflow is placed in the carry.

The end result is thus: `0111`

Now, let's have a look at the [status bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_register).

- Z: "Indicates that the result of an arithmetic or logical operation (or, sometimes, a load) was zero." *Is `0111` zero?*
- V: "Indicates that the signed result of an operation is too large to fit in the register width using twos complement representation." *Did we have an overflow?*
- C: "used to indicate when an arithmetic carry or borrow has been generated out of the most significant ALU bit position." *Was the MSB carried out?*
- N: "Indicates that the result of a mathematical operation is negative." *Is the result negative?*

Comment: Ok, so they're all 1 then...except Z

Comment: @Sim Almost. Is the result negative?

Comment: ah crap it is isn't it! since its 10111 = -9

Comment: @Sim the result isn't 10111. The result is 0111. [Is that negative?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twos_complement) If so, N=1. If not, N=0.

Comment: Oh right getting confused again, its just 7 which is not negative so N is 0, I just thought about that myself since 1 = true 0 = false was wondering why i thought you said it was wrong when i had it as 1, thanks alot Camil

Comment: @Sim good luck with your study!

Comment: its slow but getting there! Thanks for the help again

Comment: It's good to witness the curtain rise on another glorious morning of learning. I mean that honestly in case there are the cynical types amongst us